# With $TERM='screen-256color' under tmux, HOME and END keys don't work. Why?

Tags: bash, terminal, tmux

I have tmux set up with `$TERM` being set to `screen-256color` correctly. This works fine, and colours are set correctly, however it prevents me from sending `HOME` and `END` keys to the terminal, which are instead printed as `F\n` and `H\n`.

I should add that home appears to work in irssi, but not vim. Home seems to send (According to `Ctrl+v <HOME>`), `^[OH`

It may be worth adding that I am well aware of the ability to use `^` and `$` to move to the start and end of the lines, however `$` does not go to the end, rather the penultimate character, and I prefer to use `HOME` and `END` (as I can under other $TERM settings).

Can anyone explain why this is, and how I can fix it?

As a part-way fix, I set the vim keybindings to map a `<Home>` and `<End>` keypress to `<Esc>OH` and `<Esc>OF`. This isn't ideal, but works for the moment! See https://github.com/jvc26/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc for details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The above mapping solution doesn't affect the command mode or visual mode.  The following is a more ideal solution until either tmux or vim fixes the bug (put in your **.vimrc**):

```
""""""""""""""
" tmux fixes "
""""""""""""""
" Handle tmux $TERM quirks in vim
if $TERM =~ '^screen-256color'
    map <Esc>OH <Home>
    map! <Esc>OH <Home>
    map <Esc>OF <End>
    map! <Esc>OF <End>
endif
```

Comment: is there no way to fix "$" going to the end?

Comment: Is there a bug filed somewhere that I can track?

Answer (score 3):

As a fix, I set the vim keybindings to map a `<Home>` and `<End>` keypress to `<Esc>OH` and `<Esc>OF`.

```
" Handle TERM quirks in vim
if $TERM =~ '^screen-256color'
    set t_Co=256
    nmap <Esc>OH <Home>
    imap <Esc>OH <Home>
    nmap <Esc>OF <End>
    imap <Esc>OF <End>
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to set the keybindings in the `.inputrc` as explained on archlinux [Home_and_End_keys_not_working](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Home_and_End_keys_not_working) or `.zshrc` as on  [zshwiki/zle/bindkeys](http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/bindkeys).  This other stackoverflow question has some additional useful tips [home-end-keys-do-not-work-in-tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600188/home-end-keys-do-not-work-in-tmux)