# Home/End keys do not work in tmux

Tags: linux, bash, tmux

I'm currently using tmux with xterm-256color $TERM variable. When in bash under tmux, pressing home/end would insert tilde characters (~). Outside of tmux the home/end keys work fine.

Using cat and tput, I could see that there was a mismatch between the generated and expected sequences:

```
$ cat -v # pressing home, then end
^[[1~^[[4~
$ tput khome | cat -v; echo
^[OH
$ tput kend | cat -v; echo
^[OF
```

To fix this, I decided to add the following to my .bashrc:

```
if [[ -n "$TMUX" ]]; then
    bind '"\e[1~":"\eOH"'
    bind '"\e[4~":"\eOF"'
fi
```

That fixed the problem for bash, however in other readline programs, such as within a REPL such as ipython, it still inserts a tilde for home/end.

Why exactly is this a problem in the first place? Why is the generated sequence different when I'm inside tmux vs outside it? How can fix this so that it's not an issue in any programs?

Comment: this is a good question for tmux config, however I would suggest you trying to get used to `ctrl-A/E/F/B/` `alt-B/F...` (emacs bind) to move cursor

Comment: btw, if this helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604150/with-term-screen-256color-under-tmux-home-and-end-keys-dont-work-why

Comment: I currently use ctrl-a for the command-key prefix in tmux (similar to screen). I looked at that post earlier, but that seems to only apply to Vim, and it's not an issue for me in Vim.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It appears the main problem is with using xterm-256color for $TERM. I switched $TERM to screen-256color and the problem went away.

Comment: My similar problem was solved by setting the keybindings using `.inputrc` (see `info readline`) or for zsh in `.zshrc` as in `http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/bindkeys`

Comment: Edit `~/.tmux.conf` and add a line `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`

Comment: This answer, also works for the same issue with GNU Screen. I just added `term "screen-256color"` to my ~/.screenrc

Comment: I had to kill the tmux session, and close the terminal, then start everything again for it to take effect.

Comment: `screen-256color` can mess some applications. I set manual bindings in .zshrc

Comment: First tried this and it seemed okay but for me modifying the `.tmux.conf` as in @sumanta's answer turned out to work best.

Answer (score 64):

**Add the following to your `.tmux.conf`:**

```
bind-key -n Home send Escape "OH"
bind-key -n End send Escape "OF"
```

**And you're done!**

---

## Explanation

After attempting each one of these, and several others I saw while perusing other answers and documentation, this finally worked for me in every scenario I threw at it. I can't promise the same for you, because everyone's scenarios are different, but this is what I ended up with.

This was discovered after introducing the same trial/error and logic from a somewhat relevant article that is no longer available. The key is where the translation is occurring; in my case, this happens within my `.tmux.conf`, rather than `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` (mainly because my home/end worked fine outside of `tmux`)

### Debugging

You can debug this issue by using `cat -v`.

Run `cat -v`, then press the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys. Exit using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

```
$ cat -v
```

Here's what my output looked like within `tmux using zsh`, `zsh`, and `bash`:

**tmux**

```
➜  ~ cat -v
^[[1~^[[4~^C
```

**zsh**

```
➜  ~ cat -v
^[[H^[[F
```

**bash**

```
bash-3.2$ cat -v
^[[H^[[F
```

### Solutioning

Compare the above examples to what we're expecting to see, by pairing `tput` with `cat -v`:

```
$ tput khome | cat -v; echo
^[OH
$ tput kend | cat -v; echo
^[OF
```

### Conclusion

Because this problem exists solely within `tmux`, and not within the shells themselves, I opted to make the bind changes within the tmux configuration instead. By using `bind-key` paired with `send`, we can use the `Escape` keyword paired with the sequence we want to achieve our translation. Thus:

```
bind-key -n NAME_OF_KEY send Escape SEQUENCE_GOES_HERE
```

This debugging and solutioning process can be applied to any other key translation issues. But, don't go too crazy. Some keys are mapped to certain escape sequences for a reason. Notice how `bash` and `zsh` received the `^[[H` sequence for <kbd>Home</kbd> instead of `^[OH`; it's probably not recommended we override this in our `.zshrc` unless we're having major issues with this in `zsh`.

Comment: This problem disappeared for me with tmux 2.6 and `set-window-option -g xterm-keys on` in tmux, but this looks like a great answer that would help people with multiple terminal configurations.

Comment: I like this option because I wanted to use xterm-256color, as it seemed to be my only TERM that supported italics. Well, it also didn’t have a working Home/End until I added your two `bind-key` commands to my config. The `Escape` is very important, I found. Other answers omitted that and they don’t work for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm using tmux 3.1 and this started to happen after I started to used `set-window-option -g vi` so I think this is the best answer cause can work in any key modes. Nice explanation.

Comment: @zzxyz would you mind making your suggestion `set-window-option -g xterm-keys on` into an answer? It fixed the problem for me too, and I almost missed it at first glance.

Comment: I actually had `^[OH` & `^[OF` for both within the tmux and outside of the tmux.
But for some unknown reason, HOME/END key doesn't work only for the terminal within the tmux.

I had to manually add below to the `.zshrc` to fix this issue.

bindkey  "^[OH"   beginning-of-line                        
bindkey  "^[OF"   end-of-line

Comment: @LazyRen Nice! Yeah, I've had scenarios like that as well, and this style of debugging really helped to figure out which layer the problem was actually in.

Answer (score 37):

In tmux 2.0, you can just add these 2 lines in your `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind -n End send-key C-e
bind -n Home send-key C-a
```

Comment: That will only work for readline (and Emacs) and will have unintended consequences elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, vim does not care for this.

Comment: @zzxyz Found a better solution below that finally fixed it. Curious if it fits your scenario as well.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to stay with xterm-256color in tmux for some reason - use [arch solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Home_and_End_keys_not_working) with inputrc. I tested it in tmux with rxvt, ruby irb, python, lua and home/end keys are ok. Probably every readline app will be ok.

**From the arch wiki:**

First things first:

> **do not set $TERM manually - let the terminal do it.**

---

> Many command line applications use the Readline library to read input. So properly configuring Readline can fix Home and End in many cases.

the default /etc/inputrc file does not include a mapping for home/end keys.

To check what the emitted escape sequence for these keys is:

```
1. Ctrl + V
2. Home
3. Spacebar
4. Ctrl + V
5. End
```

this will probably print: `$ ^[[1~ ^[[4~`. So you have to add a mapping for these sequences to your inputrc (/etc/inputrc to be globally, or only for your user ~/.inputrc):

```
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
```

Comment: I was overriding TERM that was the cause of all my problems thanks for the link

Comment: The reason most people would be running tmux under xterm-256 is because they are running a slightly old version of Ubuntu, which has an ancient tmux package.  Upgrade your tmux!

Comment: honestly the onnly real good answer here, only you should not "just" put a link to a wiki here but also the excerpt of the wiki on how to solve the problem. I think this way many people miss out on it

Answer (score 11):

In my case it was a problem with zsh in tmux (bash in tmux was ok).
None of the other anwsers here worked for me.

But adding this to `.zshrc` fixed it:

```
bindkey "\E[1~" beginning-of-line
bindkey "\E[4~" end-of-line
```

Besides that I also have:

```
bindkey "\E[H" beginning-of-line
bindkey "\E[F" end-of-line
bindkey "\E[3~" delete-char
```

Comment: I did something similar, as actually this had nothing to do with tmux in my case, just writing it down in case it helps someone else: ``bindkey "^[OF" end-of-line`` and ``bindkey "^[OH" beginning-of-line``

Answer (score 6):

From [tmux FAQ](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-make-modified-function-and-arrow-keys-like-c-up-m-pageup-work-inside-tmux):

> PLEASE NOTE: most display problems are due to incorrect TERM! Before
>   reporting problems make SURE that TERM settings are correct inside and
>   outside tmux.
>
> Inside tmux TERM must be "screen", "tmux" or similar (such as
>   "tmux-256color"). Don't bother reporting problems where it isn't!
>
> Outside, it should match your terminal: particularly, use "rxvt" for
>   rxvt and derivatives.

Add the following command to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal tmux-256color
```

PS: any solution involving binding the keys explicitly is a hack, and as such bound to fail.

Comment: I was actually having problems because I was using the `bind -n End`/`bind -n Home` hack in my `.tmux.conf` end then I fixed my `TERM`. So, definitely, do it right and fix your TERM.

Comment: Re: "PS: any solution involving binding the keys explicitly is a hack, and as such bound to fail."... No variation of `tmux`, `screen`, `tmux-256color`, or `screen-256color` worked for me. Only Swivel's keybinding solution worked for me. macOS, zsh, tmux 2.4, under various terminal emulators.

Comment: @ModusPwnins notice you need the correct TERM both outside (i.e. your terminal) and inside TMUX. They would be different values, this answer only gives the correct value for inside tmux. You need to figure out the outside value. Assuming iterm2, see https://iterm2.com/faq.html

Answer (score 3):

`set-window-option -g xterm-keys on`

This should work in tmux 2.6 and later. (`tmux -V` to check)  If you are using an older version than that, you're probably running an older Ubuntu and you should definitely consider pointing at a ppa with backports.

This definitely doesn't work with kitty, and is effectively "hardcoding" the terminal in terms of input, but it is better than hardcoding specific keys.

Answer (score 1):

So I don't have enough points to comment,so I'll say it here instead. I believe the preferred solution is using 
`set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` in your `~/.tmux.conf`. I actually had this problem a while ago and decided to go with sumanta's solution :

```
bind -n End send-key C-e
bind -n Home send-key C-a
```

However I had forgotten I left this in here and ended up having a similar issue with vim (home and end were copy pasting from registers) instead of zsh. In short bind DOES affect vim.

Answer (score 1):

I wasted a lot of time trying all off the above.
In the end I reverted to barbarism:

```
sudo apt purge tmux
sudo apt install tmux
```

fixed it for me.